# does this affect speed or should i go with normal method of displaying image

Tags: php, image

i am displaying an image usign `readfile()` function of php

HMTL:

```
<img src='image.php?id=232'/>
```

PHP: image.php

```
<?php
   $id=$_GET["id"];
   if(image_view_allow($id)){
     $path=get_image_path($id);
     readfile($path);
   }else{
     readfile("images/not_allow.png");
   }
```

`image_view_allow` and `get_image_path` is two that i have defined to check validation and get path
I am doing this because i want show image only to the allow person.

Does this affect speed of downloading an image ?
what is normal(means direct path in src attribute of img tag) or trick that is shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loading an image probably same,but it is always better if you handle images with **php**, because when you resize image with php you load the needed size. But with **html** you load the bigger size than you need and resize.

Answer (score 0):

first -> Does this affect speed of downloading an image ?
answer: no, because when the page is loaded, the php code is already translated to html before page is loaded in the borwser.

second -> what is normal(means direct path in src attribute of img tag) or trick that is shown above?
answer: both are same as both involve php code. When code executes in either way it will enter the source of the image in the image tag.

Comment: think there more than one img tag in html file and also some html codes so it still the same ?

Comment: then it depends upon the size of the image and the load your server can take ... further for each img tag if you are looping this code again and again `$id=$_GET["id"];
    if(image_view_allow($id)){
     $path=get_image_path($id);
     readfile($path);
   }else{
     readfile("images/not_allow.png");
   }` then it might be time consuming.